# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. even importing CommonModule/BrowserModule

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular2-directives, angular6

```html
Datatable.component. html
 
 <tr *ngFor="let articles of art">
```

I have added CommonModule/BrowserModule in appmodule/Datatablemodule nothing works....`same kind of error in FormBuilder also when using "form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">" even imported the @angular/forms

```js
//app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './/app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {AddArticleModule} from './pages/add-articles/add-article.module';
import {DatatablesModule} from './pages/datatables/datatables.module';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     HttpClientModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     LayoutModule,
     ReactiveFormsModule,
     AddArticleModule,
     DatatablesModule
   ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],


  providers: [ScriptLoaderService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
//Datatables
.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: []
})
export class DatatablesModule {}
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4:ngFor inside html not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739603/angular-4ngfor-inside-html-not-working)

Comment: can you share your datatable.component.ts file?

Comment: Is the error happening in the browser or the test environment?

Comment: You must include your DatatablesComponent in "declarations" of your DatatablesModule.ts. TIP: each Component must be in a "declarations" of one and only one module

Comment: go this error after adding component in datatableModule.ts        -------Error: Type DatatablesComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppRoutingModule and DatatablesModule! Please consider moving DatatablesComponent to a higher module that imports AppRoutingModule and DatatablesModule.